# Dynamic anchor popup open outside of map container

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, mapbox-gl-js

We have popups displayed outside of the map container when they open around the edge of the map. However if the map is moved, popups will be display with the correct anchor to fit inside the map container.

When we inspect the DOM we can see that popups have not the right anchor class always "bottom (see screenshoots).

```
// init Map
let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: "map", // container id
        // style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        style: "mapbox://styles/kevin-fabre/ck8a28d160noh1imv3a9abrlu", // stylesheet location
        bounds: [
          [bbox[0], bbox[1]],
          [bbox[2], bbox[3]]
        ],
        maxBounds: this.bboxToBounds(this.getMaxBbox()),
      });

//Popups
let hoverPopup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
        offset: 32,
        closeButton: false,
        closeOnClick: true
      });
      let clickPopup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
        offset: 32,
        closeButton: false,
        closeOnClick: true
      });

// how we add popup to the map
map.on("displayClickPopup", e => {
    layerIpPopUp = e.features[0].properties.apiId;
    let coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
    // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
    // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
    // over the copy being pointed to.
    while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
      coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
    }
    clickPopup
      .setHTML('<div id="vue-popup-content"></div>')
      .setLngLat(coordinates)
      .addTo(map);
    const popupInstance = new CarouselPopUpClass({
      store,
      i18n,
      router,
      propsData: {
        posts: JSON.parse(e.features[0].properties.posts),
        currentApiId: e.features[0].properties.apiId
      }
    });
    popupInstance.$mount("#vue-popup-content");
  });
```

We are also using vuejs and vuetify inside popups.

**Have we done something that cause the anchor to be always "down" when popups open ?**

Thanks

[image: screenshoot]
[image: popup element]
[image: mapcontainer]

Comment: What's `CarouselPopUpClass`?

Comment: Hi Zim, it's a vuejs instance that is mounted to <div #vue-popup-content"></div>
It is initiate like this: const CarouselPopUpClass = Vue.extend(CarouselPopUp);

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve, and what is going wrong. Are you able to express those first two sentences differently?

Comment: Hello Steve, Of course, as you can see on the screenshoot, if we click on a symbol next to the map borders, a popup will be displayed with a bottom anchor. We haven't set anchor position for popus. Now If we move the map, the anchor property of the same popup will change and the popup will appear inside map view.
Our problem is why this dynamic change of anchor position doesn't happen when we click on a symbol if the symbol is to close to map borders ?

Answer (score 0):

I went back to the article that helped us to add vuejs component inside popup. 
At the end of the article it is described that we need to update the popup "after mount"

```
popup._update();
```

[The article](https://tech.beyondtracks.com/posts/mapbox-gl-popups-with-vue/)

Answer (score 0):

setting anchor property to 'bottom' will fix this problem